# Set variable with multiple int values and use IN with integer column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server I'd like to do something to this effect...

```
DECLARE @Values varchar(1000)
SET @Values = '1, 2, 3'

SELECT blah  
FROM foo
WHERE IntegerColumn IN (@Values)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: Thanks Goose thas what I was loking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)